# Can I upgrade my laptop's screen with a different laptop's screen?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, laptop-display

I have a Samsung notebook  with a 14" 1366x768 resolution screen. I have found a replacement laptop site that sells Samsung 14" 1600x900 screen  with the same connector type.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, but you need to do more research. You need to determine not only if the connector type is compatible, but if the screen itself can be mounted in the laptop casing. Generally speaking I would only attempt to do this if the replacement screen came out the exact same model of laptop.

That being said, even if they are compatible, removing/replacing the screen can be difficult. LCD screens in laptops are compact and fragile, and can be particularly vulnerable to damage during installation and removal. On some laptops, the panel may be held in by screws, but sometimes the screens are glued into place.

I would strongly advise you to do the following:

1. Ensure that the replacement screen came from a compatible model or was designed specifically for your model
   -and
2. Find a repair manual or detailed panel replacement instructions for your particular model so you can gauge whether or not you have the technical expertise to pull off the replacement.

Comment: Just to add, you need to make sure the resolution is supported, and most importantly that your display's power supply is the same voltage. Differing voltages will at best stop the screen from turning on, and at worst cook your brand new display.

Comment: I did some research,i found out that both of the screens has the same part number. My laptop is np530u4c.
http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/section/search/index.php?section=products&model=NP530U4BL&brand=Samsung

http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/model/Samsung/NP700Z3A-S03US/