# How to upgrade max screen resolution on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, graphics-card, resolution

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

This is my monitor(graphics) card information

And now my laptop (DELL-Inspiron-N4050) has HD resolution (1366x768):

```
 dimensions:    1366x768 pixels (361x203 millimeters)
```

And I wanna know that how can I upgrade it FHD And I googled what max resolution supports by my monitor(graphics) card. So I find this site (offical site of amd):

[Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series](http://www.amd.com/pt-br/products/graphics/notebook/7400m)

It says it support up to `Max resolution: 2048x1536` but Currently I used resolution is almost 50% lower than the max resolution.

How can I solve this issue. Caused by driver? or what? if the caused by driver how can I update driver?

And my OS information is like that : lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 1):

Your screen panel supports only 1366x768 resolution. The GPU can drive only only up to the resolution that your panel supports. There's nothing to fix, this is per design. The only way to increase the resolution to FullHD is to replace the panel, which isn't really a trivial task(and I'm not even sure if that's possible).

Better alternative is to buy a monitor & connect it to the laptop & enable extended display mode.

Comment: How can I find that which panel support for my laptop?

Comment: like I said, there's no easy way. Open the laptop, find the panel details, search on the Internet. See here: http://superuser.com/questions/515962/can-i-upgrade-my-laptops-screen-with-a-different-laptops-screen

Comment: One more thing I wondered is that ;

For example I watch a movie at 480p and then the same movie at 720p And the result is there are so different between their qualities. But NO effect between 720p-1080p on my laptop but both of video are playable on my machine.

Comment: you screen isn't capable of showing the increased number of pixels between the 2 videos

Comment: Okey so I can watch it only up to 720p. Am I right?

Comment: you can watch 720p or higher, but you aren't likely to see any great difference